# Highlighting cells if it contains a specific text from a list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

In column [A] I have a list of specific company names. In columns [B], [C], [D] etc. I also have company names. I would like to highlight all cells containing a specific company name listed in [A]. Let's say [A] contains "XYZ". If [B], [C], [D] etc. also contains "XYZ" then I would like to highlight every single one of those cells.

I tried solving this with Conditional Formatting -> Highlight Cells Rules -> Text that Contains, but this doesn't work when you have a list of strings. I also tried using conditional formatting with a COUNTIF-formula, however I was unsuccessful. I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Under 'Select a Rule Type:', select 'Use a formula to determine which cells to format and enter a formula like this:

=AND($B2="xyz",$C2="xyz",$D2="xyz")

Then you can copy and paste-special (format) to the other columns and rows.

Comment: Forgot to add that you must select the Format button and then select Fill from the ribbon to set your highlight color, after entering the formula.

Comment: I should clarify that if you were in cell b2 and set the CF, you would want to copy that formatting to the other desired rows and columns. I do it that way to avoid adding the rule to entire columns.

Answer (score 0):

Since *a specific company name* in ColumnA, and not enough other details, I am assuming in A1.

Clear CF from B:D (or further to the right) select ColumnsB:D (or further to the right) and Format - Conditional formatting..., **Custom formula is** and:

```
=B1=$A$1
```

with highlighting of your choice. <kbd>Done</kbd>.